# Компиляция зависимых SASS SCSS файлов

Tags: frontend, sass, scss, node-sass

Допустим у меня есть следующая структура файлов стилей:

`-scss
--things
---variables.scss
---reset.scss
--main.scss`

Как правильно написать npm скрипт который не будет компилировать файлы из папки things, но при их изменении будет пересобирать main.scss?

Comment: Переименуйте variables.scss в _variables.scss и reset.scss в _reset.scss. Дальше как обычно sass --watch на весь каталог.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написал @MAX у вас должна быть следующая структура файлов:

```
--scss
--things
---_variables.scss
---_reset.scss
--main.scss
```

В `main.scss` следующий код

```
@import 'things/reset';
@import 'things/variables';
```

В `package.json` добавить комаду `sass --watch <input folder>:<output folder>` код:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "sass --watch scss:css",
 }
```